# How do we implement Parameter free generalised Moment limiter in 1D Case in Discontinuous Galerkin methods?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, discontinuous-galerkin, wave-propagation

I am referring to this paper:-

"A Parameter-Free Generalized Moment Limiter for High-
Order Methods on Unstructured Grids " by Michael Yang and Z.J. Wang.

http://dept.ku.edu/~cfdku/papers/AIAA-2009-605.pdf

They have implemented a general limiter which doesn't require any user input. In the process, they have represented the solution in the cell in terms of the average of derivatives (Eqn. 28 of paper). [image]

Can someone please explain how was this representation attained. The understanding of this is a quite high priority for me. Please help.